# Unable to send command from IoT Central to PyPortal

Tags: python, iot, azure-iot-central, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm currently using a PyPortal in a automated plant monitoring and watering IoT system, connected to IoT Central.
The device is connected in IoT Central, however when i send the command from IoT Central to my PyPortal it does not work and shows either this error
[Gateway timeout waiting for device 1bic1gfu8zk in application 48e39735-0f9a-44dc-a50c-e5debf12baee to return the request.]
or this issue where by the response from the device is empty. The below code is raw data from IoT Central:

```
{
    "waterPlant": {
        "Value": ""
    },
    "_eventtype": "Command response",
    "_timestamp": "2022-02-14T08:09:43.473Z"
}
```

My PyPortal code is based on this link: https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/azureiot/en/latest/examples.html#id6

PyPortal code to receive command:

```
def command_executed(waterPlant: str, payload) -> IoTResponse:
                print("Command ", waterPlant, " executed with payload", str(payload))
                # return a status code and message to indicate if the command was handled correctly
                return IoTResponse(200, "OK"),
device.on_command_executed = command_executed
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your PyPortal ever triggers "command_executed" while you debug it? See [How to use commands in an Azure IoT Central solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-use-commands). It may help if you select "Queue if offline" option.

Comment: @asergaz Not sure if it triggers it. Sometimes IoT Central just tells me "Gateway timeout" while on other occasions it will return a response with an empty value.

Comment: It would help if you can debug your PyPortal and check if it hits it :). Let us know.